# create relationship class with stand alone python script

Tags: arcpy, relationship-class, error-000628, error-000622

I have created a relationship class in arc catalog using the same arguments I'm using below, however if I try and create it using the script below I get:

> arcgisscripting.ExecuteError: ERROR 000622: Failed to execute (Create
>   Relationship Class). Parameters are not valid. ERROR 000628: Cannot
>   set input into parameter attributed.

Following is the script I'm using:

```
import arcpy
from arcpy import env

env.workspace = "C:\a.gdb"

origin_table = "a.gdb\Trail_meta"
destination_table = "a.gdb\trails_mfg"
out_relationship_class = "a.gdb\t3meta"
relationship_type = "SIMPLE"
forward_label = "Attributes from meta"
backward_label = "Attributes from trail"
message_direction = "NONE"
cardinality = "ONE_TO_MANY"
attributed = "NONE"
origin_primary_key = "OBJECTID"
origin_foreign_key = "TRAIL_NAME"

arcpy.CreateRelationshipClass_management(origin_table,destination_table,out_relationship_class,forward_label,backward_label,message_direction,cardinality,attributed,origin_primary_key,origin_foreign_key)
```

Comment: At a quick glance, since you're setting your environment variable `env.workspace`, I think you may be misleading the script by re-stating the name of the database in your variables `origin_table`,`destination_table`, and `relationship_type`. Try removing "a.gdb\" from these strings and see what happens.

Comment: Added an answer below based on the comment above.

Comment: yeah, tried that. Didn't help (I only put that in because of this sample code) http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//0017000000mn000000

Comment: When I see env.workspace = "C:\a.gdb" my first thought is "shouldn't that be one of the following:"  env.workspace = "C:\\a.gdb", env.workspace = "C:/a.gdb" or env.workspace = r"C:\a.gdb"

Comment: Yep, backslash is an [escape character](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Escape_character) in Python. Gotta look out for that especially on Windows where your filesystem paths almost always contain backslashes.

Answer (score 2):

Since you're setting your environment variable env.workspace, I think you may be misleading the tool by re-stating the name of the database in your variables: `origin_table`,`destination_table`, and `relationship_type`.

What the tool sees this:

```
origin_table = "a.gdb\a.gdb\Trail_meta"
destination_table = "a.gdb\a.gdb\trails_mfg"
out_relationship_class = "a.gdb\a.gdb\t3meta"
```

Redefine your variables to this:

```
origin_table = "Trail_meta"
destination_table = "trails_mfg"
out_relationship_class = "t3meta"
```

Also, it looks like all you want to import is the `env` module from `arcpy`, you can do that by simply using the `from arcpy import env` command instead of importing the entire `arcpy` module first. This may save you a bit of time when running the script.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks this post actually helped me get this working.  Sorry this is probably long since too late.

I believe the problem in the original post is that the relationship_type parameter is missing in the function call, thus causing an invalid parameter to be associated with the "attributed" parameter.  Just change the function call to the following:

```
arcpy.CreateRelationshipClass_management(origin_table,destination_table,out_relationship_class,relationship_type,forward_label,backward_label,message_direction,cardinality,attributed,origin_primary_key,origin_foreign_key)
```